# How to efficienty up-sample hourly averages in a Series?

Tags: pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I had a look to the "sql-like" windows function for pandas, and to "rolling".
However, it seems to me I can't have a condition on timestamps in the index, but maybe I'm wrong.
So far, I've been writing this very inefficient code to have an hourly average as a window function.
Anyone knowing a quicker and nicer method?

```
def avg_on_hour(data: pd.Series()):
    new_series = pd.Series()
    start_date = data.index.min()
    end_date = data.index.max()
    delta = dt.timedelta(hours=1)
    this_time = start_date
    while this_time < end_date:
        this_date = this_time.date()
        this_hour = this_time.hour
        day_slice = data[(data.index.date == this_date) & (data.index.hour == this_hour)]
        day_avg = day_slice.mean()
        day_slice.iloc[:] = day_avg
        new_series = new_series.append(day_slice, verify_integrity=True)
        this_time = this_time + delta
    return new_series
```

Example:
[image: Sample extract from a Series]

Comment: Pandas has rolling on datetime, given that the series is datetime indexed: `series.rolling('1H').mean()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has rolling on datetime, given that the series is datetime indexed

```
# sample data:
np.random.seed(1)
size=10
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(size), 
              index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', freq='7T', periods=size))

# rolling mean
series.rolling('1H').mean()
```

Output:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00    0.417022
2020-01-01 00:07:00    0.568673
2020-01-01 00:14:00    0.379154
2020-01-01 00:21:00    0.359948
2020-01-01 00:28:00    0.317310
2020-01-01 00:35:00    0.279815
2020-01-01 00:42:00    0.266450
2020-01-01 00:49:00    0.276339
2020-01-01 00:56:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 01:03:00    0.303252
Freq: 7T, dtype: float64
```

---

**Update**: from your comment, it looks like you are looking for `groupby`:

```
s.groupby(s.index.floor('H')).transform('mean')
```

or

```
s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H')).transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 00:07:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 00:14:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 00:21:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 00:28:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 00:35:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 00:42:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 00:49:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 00:56:00    0.289720
2020-01-01 01:03:00    0.538817
Freq: 7T, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yeah, maybe I have expressed myself not quite right.
I'd like to have a series with the same value over all the timestamps that refer to the same hour of the day. So, it's like an aggregate function but then up-sampled again to the original interval.
For example, if I find the average value of the Series between 2020-08-01 11:00:00 and 2020-08-01 12:00:00 is (say) 500, I'd like a column where i get 500 at each timestamp in that interval. I have added a sample picture to my answer.

Comment: That's not rolling. That's just `groupby`. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, brilliant. I didn't know the usage of 'transform' and 'pd.Grouper'